# Strategy for real device deployment on android

Tags: android, deployment

There is a multitude of available Android devices. In order to deliver a successful app, it needs to run smoothly and correctly (without crashes and with expected appearance and behavior) on various device configurations.

Is there a way to ensure an android app runs well on a device? How can "good" and "bad" devices be identified? What are strategies to deploy the app (possibly over an app-store) only on devices on which the app runs well?

Comment: My advice is to try run it on slower device.... And its an important question, add bounty to it later.

Comment: The question is not only about speed. It's also about unexpected behavior such as a crash on a device configuration. I have reformulated the question accordingly to avoid misinterpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, before the app is published to the Play store, make sure to test on a set of *different* devices: high-end, low-end, tablet, small screen, large screen etc. If you do not have access to devices, you can use an emulator. It is not exactly the same, but it comes close.

If you notice any problem areas, you can [apply filters](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) in your manifest file to limit the devices that can install your app. It is also possible to publish multiple APKs for different filter configurations, so you can make a smaller feature set available to problem devices.

As for identifying "bad" devices, as far as I know there is no easy way to do this. I would suggest keeping an eye on the crash logs in the Play store and updating the app accordingly.